# Android - how to build the application which will copy video to SD Card?

Tags: android, video, copy, sd-card

I would like to build the application which will copy the file. mp4 from the folder raw to the SD Card. Does somebody have a good guide?

Answer (score 0):

Saving files is described here [How to save files in android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) and you only have to open the resource as a stream. like so:

```
InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.name_off_file);
```

and converting an input stream to file is basic java a little explaination can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-inputstream-to-file-in-java/).